# Create Bash function which echo's into a file (syntax?)

Tags: bash, function, quoting, output-redirect

Whats the proper syntax for the below function in bashrc, which will echo a number into a file?

I've tried:

```
brightness(){
    "echo '$1' > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
}
```

I've tried many variations, but in this example when calling the function, I get:

```
brightness:1: no such file or directory: echo '250' > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes were placed incorrectly. It should be:

```
brightness(){
    echo "$1" > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
}
```

Btw, since the file is only writable by *root*, you need to use `sudo` (unless you *are* root). `tee` comes in handy here:

```
brightness(){
    echo "$1" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness > /dev/null
}
```